# How to remove the Header from syslog message while using log4j SyslogAppender in Java

Tags: java, log4j, syslog, syslog4j

I'm using the SyslogAppender of log4j version 2.17.1 (package org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender) in order to send syslog messages.

the message are sent in the next format:

```
Mar 23 17:32:24 se-demo {"id": 1,"type": "test-type","severity": "test-severity","severityScore": 50,"securityEventTimestamp": 10101,"msg": "test-description","cat": "test-category","url": "test-url","dstIps": "test-destinationIps","dstHosts": "test-destinationHosts","destinationAccount": "test-destinationAccount","destination": "test-destination","destinationType": "test-destinationType","accessedTables": "test-.accessedTables","numOfAccessedObjects": "test-numOfAccessedObjects","srcUsers": "test-sourceUsers","srcIps": "test-sourceIps","srcHosts": "test-sourceHosts","sourceApps": "test-sourceApps","userAction": "test-userAction","clusterNames": "test-clusterNames","clusterMemberNames": "test-clusterMemberNames","actionType": "test-statusType"}
```

I would like to remove the header for the message (remove the "Mar 23 17:32:24 se-demo") and send only the message itself.

My appender is built with java code:

```
 private SyslogAppender createSyslogAppender(SyslogSendProtocolType protocol, SyslogFacilityType syslogFacilityType, String host, int port, boolean ignoreExceptions, String appenderName, Configuration config) {
        return SyslogAppender.createAppender(
                host,
                port,
                protocol.name(),
                null,
                5000,
                2000,
                true,
                appenderName,
                true,
                ignoreExceptions,
                Facility.toFacility(syslogFacilityType.name()),
                null,
                Rfc5424Layout.DEFAULT_ENTERPRISE_NUMBER,
                true,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                true,
                null,
                appenderName,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                config,
                Charset.forName("UTF-8"),
                null,
                new LoggerFields[]{},
                true);
    }
```

I attached also a printscreen of the constructor above so you can the the description of each member
[image]

I cannot find any method on that appender that I can configure whether to remove the header or not.
Any ideas?

Comment: What syslog server are you using? The message example you provide is not in Log4j's wire format, but has already been transformed by your syslog server. You can surely configure the server to write the messages in another format.

Comment: I used rsyslog and kiwi. In both the messege was recevied with header. You say that in order to get rid of fhe header, I dont need to change my java code but I need to change something in the syslog server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark**: the factory method with more than 30 arguments is deprecated for a reason: nowadays most Log4j2 components have builders that render the code more legible.

You can easily remove the header from the Syslog messages sent by Log4j2, by replacing the appender's layout:

```java
final Layout layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout(config);
SyslogAppender.newSyslogAppenderBuilder()//
        .setConfiguration(config)
        .setLayout(layout)
        .build();
```

However I **wouldn't recommend** this path: you'll just loose information and the syslog server will just recreate the missing header.

A more proper solution would go in the opposite direction:

- Your Syslog appender is using the old BSD syslog format. Changing the format to [RFC5424](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5424), will allow you to send messages unambiguously interpreted by all modern Syslog servers:

  ```java
  SyslogAppender.newSyslogAppenderBuilder()
          .setConfiguration(config)
          .setName(appenderName)
          .setFormat("RFC5424")
          .setAppName("myApp")
          .build();
  ```
- Configure your syslog server to only save the message part. For RSyslog this can be done using:

  ```
  $template PlainMessageFormat,"%msg%\n"

  :programname, startswith, "myApp" {
      action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/test.log" Template="PlainMessageFormat")
      stop
  }
  ```

  If you are using RSylog 8.3.0 or later you can also dump the whole message as JSON:

  ```
  $template JsonMessageFormat,"%jsonmesg%\n"
  ```

Comment: Thank for the answer! that was really helpful!